# I think I'm installing Django, but it doesn't seem to be there

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip, python-venv

Mysterious. I may not understand virtualenv sufficiently to use it.
I created what I thought was a virtual environment:

```
   pip3 -m venv myenv

   pip3 install --ignore-installed django~=2.0.0
   Collecting django~=2.0.0
     Using cached Django-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
   Collecting pytz (from django~=2.0.0)
     Using cached pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   Installing collected packages: pytz, django
   Successfully installed django-2.0.1 pytz-2017.3
   001b639f6f87:myenv admin$ ls
   bin  include  lib  pyvenv.cfg
```

So, where is Django?

Actually, this may not be a virtualenv question. Run the same
command in a non-venv directory with the same result: no Django.

So, I think, maybe there is an issue with Django 2.0 of which I am
unaware. Let's try 1.11:

```
001b639f6f87:django-test admin$ pip3 install --ignore-installed
django~=1.11.0
Collecting django~=1.11.0
  Downloading Django-1.11.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
    100%
|&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&
#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#
9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;| 7.0MB 
108kB/s 
Collecting pytz (from django~=1.11.0)
  Using cached pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pytz, django
Successfully installed django-2.0.1 pytz-2017.3
001b639f6f87:django-test admin$ ls
001b639f6f87:django-test admin$ ls -l
001b639f6f87:django-test admin$
```

Obviously, unclear on something, but not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: Did you check python3's site-packages?

Answer (score 0):

Django should be installed in `/path/to/your/venv/lib/python3.x/site-packages/`

You can check this in the Python shell by importing django then checking `django.__file__`.

```
>>> import django
>>> django.__file__
'/path/to/your/venv/lib/python3.x/site-packages/django/__init__.py'
```

Note that it doesn't really matter where Django has been installed to. The key thing is that `import django` works after you have activated your virtual environment.

Comment: python and django are installed on the computer, but I'm not sure that is the key.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does matter where Django as been installed to. Using virtual environments is strongly recommended. Do it as follows:

If you don't have 'virtualenv' installed, first install it.

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

1. Install virtualenv if you don't have it.
2. `virtualenv venv -p python3`
3. Now you've created a virtual environment named 'venv'.
4. `source venv/bin/activate`
5. Now. you're gonna see a 'venv' label on your terminal. That means you've successfully created the virtual environment and you're on it. After that, every package you'll install will be in the /venv folder.

Using virtual environment is good for isolation, your project will be clean and you'll be able to keep track of the libraries you use on the project. If you decide to destroy your project, all you have to do is deleting the venv folder and it is all clean.

6. `pip3 freeze` command shows the installed libraries in your virtual environment. Initially it'll be empty.
7. `pip3 install django`
8. This will install django and if you run the command on step 6, you'll see django there.

Comment: Hmm. A few things. This all started as I tried to follow the djangogirls tutorial. I'm not sure if I missed things in the tutorial, and/or missed configuration problems.

I did confirm that I had virtualenv installed, but for python 2.7. I am using python 3.6.3. Following your instructions and using pip3, that is corrected.

I now have a virtual environment on Dropbox (goal is to be able to access this from both the home desktop, and the laptop). If I understand correctly, from whichever machine, when I want to work on this site, I will need to run the active command?

Comment: I wasn't very clear when I said that it doesn't matter where Django is installed to. Yes, it's important that you install it in the virtual environment. My point is that the location of the package in the virtual environment (e.g. in `/path/to/venv/lib/python3.x/site-packages/`) is an implementation detail that doesn't really matter.

Comment: @AriDavidow Yes, before starting to work, you have to activate your virtual environment and see the (venv) label on your terminal. That'll make you able to use django and all the libraries on your project. But dropbox is not a good way to work from multiple machines. You have to use version control system like git. I recommend bitbucket or github. When you have git, all of your changes on the project will be tracked by git and you can use it in any computer.

Comment: @Alasdair I just re-read your answer and saw what you mean :) I guess i just focused on the 'it doesn't really matter ...' part of the answer :)

Comment: Yes--perhaps not obvious, but understood by me that the code, itself, belongs in a version control system. Dropbox is just the convenient local "place" to work on it without needing to pull the code to separately maintained development environments on two (or more) machines.